# close Alloy UI modal window

Tags: modal-dialog, alloy-ui

I have used Alloy UI Modal window. The code is:

```
YUI().use(
          'aui-modal',
          function(Y) {
            var modal = new Y.Modal(
              {
                bodyContent:'test',
                centered: true,
                headerContent:headerContent,
                modal: true,
                render: '#testModal',
                width: 631,
                id:'modalSource',
                destroyOnHide:true
              }
            ).render();

            modal.addToolbar(
                      [{
                          label: 'Add',
                          on: {
                            click: function() {
                                addData();
                             //modal.hide() works here but i need to close it inside addData..

                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                              label: 'Cancel',
                              on: {
                                click: function() {
                                    modal.hide();
                                }
                              }
                            }

                      ]
                    );
          }
        );
```

The function addData is in a different js file and makes an Ajax call, so I need to pass id of modal window and close it after success callback . Do you have any idea on how to get id of modal window and use modal.hide over there. Thank you

```
function addData()
{
   $('#modalSource').hide();
}
```

Comment: I tried with assigning id and using jquery inside addData function. It hides the window but does not destroy completely.

Answer (score 0):

After going through some AUI tutorials, managed to solve it..Just pass an instance of modal window into addData function and then call hide() method.

```
modal.addToolbar(
                  [{
                      label: 'Add',
                      on: {
                        click: function() {
                            addData(modal);


                        }
                      }
                    },   



 function addData(modalInstance)
 {
  //do needed stuff
   modalInstance.hide();
 }
```